# Dynamically protecting url using node.js Keycloak adapter

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, keycloak

The code from [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/tree/master/example) works for the basic case when urls are known in advance.
How to handle dynamic protection of urls by Keycloak after middleware was added and express app started? 
I was thinking about handling reading new urls from file by some node.js module which will emit the event and then the code below would handle the event. In the code of event handler, the call to `app.all('/new url', keycloak.protect())` will be added. 
I tried that but it doesn't work as expected because of the `app.use('/lap', [some_midleware])` is before the new `app.all('/new url', keycloak.protect()`
The only way i think of is modifying `app._router.stack` by inserting the new middleware before the some_midleware

```
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
var hogan = require('hogan-express');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var fs = require()
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});



var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));


var keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
});


app.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: '/logout',
  admin: '/',
  protected: '/protected/resource'
}));

app.all('/url', keycloak.protect())

app.all('*', [some_midleware])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to dynamically add new routes that get handled *before* the last route in your example (`app.use('*', ...)`).

You could do that with a separate router:

```
app.all('/url', keycloak.protect())

const router = express.Router();
app.use(router);

app.use('*', [some_midleware])
```

Then, to add new route handlers, you'd add them to `router`, not `app`:

```
router.get('/new url', keycloak.protect());
```

Because `router` is added *before* `app.use('*', ...)`, it will always get to handle requests first. Only if requests don't match any handlers will be pass the request on the handler on the last line.

Comment: sorry, i modified the answer `app.all('*', [some_midleware])` is used

Comment: @user1264304 I've edited my answer accordingly, but the method proposed remains the same :D